# jquery ui, multiple sliders with multiple functions - MATHS issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create multiple sliders for configuring a hosting package. I have 1 issues and 1 question for advice or help in the right direction. In the code below I am trying to divide the UI.VALUE from the slider by 1, this should give me the figure in money. For every 1000mb it will cost 1.00 extra. For some reason the maths divide below is being ignored. (`var cost = ui.value/1;  $( "#cost" ).val( "£" + cost  );`)

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider_storage").slider({
        value: 100,
        min: 0,
        max: 10000,
        step: 500,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#storage").val(ui.value + "MB");
            var cost = ui.value / 1;
            $("#cost").val("£" + cost);
        }
    });
    $("#slider_transfer").slider({
        value: 100,
        min: 0,
        max: 10000,
        step: 500,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#transfer").val(ui.value + "MB");
            var cost = ui.value / 1;
            $("#cost").val("£" + cost);
        }
    });
    $("#slider_cams").slider({
        value: 100,
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#cams").val(ui.value);
            var cost = ui.value / 1;
            $("#cost").val("£" + cost);
        }
    });
    $("#storage").val($("#slider").slider("value") + "MB");
    $("#cost").val("£" + $("#slider").slider("value"));
});
```

I also want the other sliders to update the price value as well as the first `slider_storage` where the maths issues is, what's the best way to do this keeping the value on subtracting and adding from the other sliders.

Here it is in js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dFwtA/

Thanks for your help in advanced :)

Comment: What do your HTML widgets look like? You seem to have four sliders: `#slider`, `#slider_storage`, `#slider_transfer` and `#slider_cams`; Each changing the same element (`#cost`)

Comment: Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/dFwtA/28/

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar mortgage calculator for myself, check the fiddle, it might help you :)

**http://jsfiddle.net/48Hpa/19/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function() {
        $( "#slider1" ).slider({
          range: "min",
          value: 36,
          min: 12,
          max: 36,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".amount1" ).val( ui.value);
              writesum();
          }
        });
        $( ".amount1" ).val($( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ));
      });

    $(function() {
        $( "#slider2" ).slider({
          range: "min",
          value: 50000,
          min: 1,
          max: 50000,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".amount2" ).val( ui.value );
              writesum();
          }
        });
        $( ".amount2" ).val( $( "#slider2" ).slider( "value" ));
      });


    function writesum() {
      var months = $('.amount1').val();
      var credits = $('.amount2').val();
      var payment = parseFloat(Number(credits) / Number(months))
      var rounded = payment.toFixed(2);
          $('.amount3').val(rounded);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this as it has some useful functionality I can learn from, I have set the script up in js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dFwtA/

Comment: I have updated the code after looking through yours, still can't get it to work, any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/dFwtA/28/

Comment: @JohnJ ... what do you want to do exactly? can you provide a paint of what you exactly want?

Comment: well on that js fiddle I am just trying to divide the number from transfer by 1 500/1 should give me 5. then the 5 will appear in the cost field

Comment: @JohnJ please take a screenshot and draw me what you exactly want to multiply and divide, etc.., and upload this paint to URL and link me the URL so I can check.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40442/discussion-between-hasan-alaca-and-john-j)

Comment: nevermind figured it out, it was because I had varchars in the numbers.. oooops

Comment: @JohnJ great. maybe you would pick me as chosen answer on the left side green tick?